# Access ajax.php URL inside the admin and in site for not logged in users

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a created a Wordpress plugin and added Angular 1.7 to that. I use ajax structure to operation my functions. This is my code in my plugin main PHP file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');
function myplugin_ajaxurl() {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";</script>';
}
```

In JS file I use `ajaxurl` for request URL. I have 2 package of HTML, CSS, JS files. Admin package which is admin page of my plugin and also use some short-codes to define some forms in view of websites. 
The problem is my ajax requests in website only work when the user is logged in. Like a submit form. If user is no logged in, request returns error 400. The problem is admin-ajax.php does not load for not logged in user. How can I do that?  I need to submit a form ajaxly to my plugin function handler file.

Comment: How are you declaring your ajax callbacks? remember the are two ways to declare an ajax callback `wp_ajax_my_action` for logged users and `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action` for anonymous users, more info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: @EnriqueChavez wow Fantastic. Problem solved just by adding ```add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'handle_ajax_request' );
```